# Centos Nano Upgrading

Tags: linux, yum, nano

I'm having a few issues with the default version of Nano...Its extremely buggy and when I scroll between characters they mysteriously change without my editing.

How do I update my nano version? The version is 2.0.9 and it doesnt have anything more recent when I do yum update nano.

The nano webpage shows 2.2.6.

Whats the best way of upgrading this?

Thanks,
D (Linux novice)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At this write time, CentOS ships the following versions of nano:

## Centos 5.9

```
nano --version
 GNU nano versión 1.3.12 (compilado 14:20:47, Jan  9 2007)
 Correo: nano@nano-editor.org   Web: http://www.nano-editor.org
 Opciones compiladas: --enable-color --enable-extra --enable-multibuffer --enable-nanorc --enable-utf8
```

## Centos 6.4

```
nano --version
 GNU nano versión 2.0.9 (compilado 07:18:28, Nov 12 2010)
 (C) 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007
 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 Correo: nano@nano-editor.org   Web: http://www.nano-editor.org
 Opciones compiladas: --enable-color --enable-extra --enable-multibuffer --enable-nanorc --enable-utf8
```

For install a new version, previously ensure remove the nano package installed with:

```
# yum remove nano
```

After you can install the rpm package from [nano download page](http://www.nano-editor.org/download.php) (for example 2.2.6 for 64 bits):

```
# rpm -ivh http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/RPMS/nano-2.2.6-1.x86_64.rpm
```

As far I see, upgrading the nano package doesn't have any compability problems in 5.9 or 6.4.

Comment: rpm -ivh http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/RPMS/nano-2.2.6-1.x86_64.rpm
Retrieving http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/RPMS/nano-2.2.6-1.x86_64.rpm
error: skipping http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/RPMS/nano-2.2.6-1.x86_64.rpm - transfer failed - Unknown or unexpected error
warning: u 0x9a24888 ctrl 0x9a25840 nrefs != 0 (www.nano-editor.org http)

Comment: I ended up installing 2.7.4 build for CentOS 6 from GhettoForge: https://centos.pkgs.org/6/ghettoforge-plus-x86_64/nano-2.7.4-3.gf.el6.x86_64.rpm.html (pick your build to suit, x86_64, i686...)

Answer (score 0):

yum update in this case.

Sometimes the distribution chooses not to upgrade to the latest version of some software (mostly for security reasons) so it might be possible that you cant install from the normal repositories.

You might find an rpm on the official website, you can install from there.

[Nano download url](http://www.nano-editor.org/download.php)

Answer (score 0):

To install last version

`yum remove nano -y`

`yum --nogpg install https://mirror.ghettoforge.org/distributions/gf/gf-release-latest.gf.el7.noarch.rpm -y`

`yum --enablerepo=gf-plus install nano -y`

**Show error after `nano /some.file` but work after press enter**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).